# Will battery drain if only positive terminal connected to circuit?

Tags: batteries, battery-operated

Lets say I have one quite large circuit consists of many components including winding and light bulbs.

The positive terminal of the battery goes directly to a winding.

If I disconnect only negative terminal, does this circuit still drain the battery?

Comment: No current will flow through the circuit. The battery might still self-discharge slowly, same as if neither terminal was connected.

Comment: I know but just doubt since the circuit is large

Comment: Why do you think the size of something that is not connected matters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current will not drain through the circuit, but if you consider the batteries leakage current, then yes, the battery will drain.

This drain rate varies according to the battery technology (lead acid, lithium, etc..) and may or may not be big enough to impact your project.

[This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27035/how-to-measure-li-po-battery-leakage) other question has some interesting remarks on battery leakage.

Answer (score 3):

The circuit needs to be closed for current to flow. If you open the circuit (disconnect a battery lead or otherwise), then the battery will not drain.